# How to get the key values present commonly between two lists?

Tags: python

I am trying to get the key values commonly  present in both `first_list`  and `second_list` as below,`first_list`  and `second_list` has `X` and `Z` as the common keys,I want to get the values corresponding to `X` and `Z` and create a final dictionary as show in `EXPECTED OUTPUT BELOW`,I have the current and expected output,can someone provide guidance on what is wrong here?

```
first_list = [{'W':['xyz','abc','def']},{'X':['1','2','3']},{'Y':['4','5','6']},{'Z':['1','5','7']}]

second_list = [{'X':True},{'Z':True}]


first_list_keys,second_list_keys = [],[]
for item in first_list:
    for key,value in item.items():
        print (key,value)
        first_list_keys.append(key)

for item in second_list:
    for key,value in item.items():
        print (key,value)
        second_list_keys.append(key)
print(first_list_keys,second_list_keys)
c = set(first_list_keys).intersection(second_list_keys)

print (c)
final_dict = {}
for item in c:
    item_dict = {}
    for data in first_list:
        for key,value in data.items():
            print (key,value)
            if key == item:
                print ('==================')
                print (value)
                item_dict['deps'] = value


                for item in c:
                    for data in second_list:
                        for key,value in data.items():
                            print (key,value)
                            if key == item:
                                print ('==================')
                                print (value)
                                item_dict['values'] = True
                final_dict[key] = item_dict
print (final_dict)
```

CURRENT OUTPUT:-

```
{'Z': {'deps': ['1', '5', '7'], 'values': True}}
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:-

```
{'X':{"deps":['1','2','3'],"values": true },'Z':{"deps":['1','5','7'],"values": true }
```

UPDATE:-

```
{'W':{"deps":['xyz','abc','def'],"values": False},'X':{"deps":['1','2','3'],"values": True },'Y':{"deps":['4','5','6'],"values":False},'Z':{"deps":['1','5','7'],"values": True }
```

Comment: Why do you expect `"values": true` when your data is `"values": True`? Is this a typo?

Comment: does the second list always contains True values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one solution.  Note that to be able to look up the keys in the second list, I first turn it into a dictionary and then work with that.  This code assumes that each dictionary in either list consists of exactly one key/value pair:

```
first_list = [{'W':['xyz','abc','def']},{'X':['1','2','3']},{'Y':['4','5','6']},{'Z':['1','5','7']}]

second_list = [{'X':True},{'Z':True}]

result ={}

# Create a map from "second_list", where for each entry in "second_list", we pull out the one
# key/value pair contained therin and then add it to the new dictionary
second_list_map = { next(iter(kv.keys())):next(iter(kv.values())) for kv in second_list}

# For each entry in the first list...
for fentry in first_list:
    # Get the one key in the entry
    key = next(iter(fentry.keys()))
    # If this key is also in the second list...
    if key in second_list_map:
        # Add the appropriate entry to the result dictionary
        result[key] = {
            "deps": fentry[key],
            "values": second_list_map[key]
        }

print(result)
```

Result:

```
{'X': {'deps': ['1', '2', '3'], 'values': True}, 'Z': {'deps': ['1', '5', '7'], 'values': True}}
```

Here's the main body for the updated requirement of retaining all the values from the first list, and noting the absence of a key in the second list with `'values': False`:

```
for fentry in first_list:
    key = next(iter(fentry.keys()))
    result[key] = {
        "deps": fentry[key],
        "values": second_list_map[key] if key in second_list_map else False
    }
```

Result:

```
{'W': {'deps': ['xyz', 'abc', 'def'], 'values': False}, 'X': {'deps': ['1', '2', '3'], 'values': True}, 'Y': {'deps': ['4', '5', '6'], 'values': False}, 'Z': {'deps': ['1', '5', '7'], 'values': True}}
```

Comment: is there a way to capture the keys present in first list and not in second_list with a `False` in the final output,I updated the question on how the output will look like

Comment: sure...........do you want an empty 'deps' or no 'deps' entry at all?

Comment: You shouldn't convert a list to a dictionary unless you want to create a list of values. You may have duplicate keys. How are you going to handle that while maintaining the order and structure of both dictionaries

Comment: @CryptoFool - There will be a 'deps' entry with the corresponding key values from list one,first_list one keys will be a superset of second_list

Comment: @carteblanche - there you go!

Comment: @JoeFerndz - we don't need to worry about duplicates in this case because we're creating a dictionary in the end with the same keys.  If there were duplicates, we wouldn't be able to represent all of the values in the final result anyway.  The OP would have to state how they want to deal with duplicates in that case.  I assumed that since the OP didn't say anything about dups, and their desired output couldn't deal with them, that dups aren't possible.

Comment: @CryptoFool seems you assume that the second_list always conatins keys with value `True`

Comment: @RishabhKumar - yeah, at the moment.  The OP wasn't very clear about that.  If they can be True or False, then what good does it do to always put False in for entries that have no entry in the second_list.  It would be trivial to update the code to preserve the True/False state from second_list.  I just figured it didn't matter either way for demonstrating what the OP really wanted help with. - OTOH....fixed! (thanks for prodding me to go back and make that improvement)

Comment: @CryptoFool, I used `[* fentry.items()][0]` to get key and val. Looks like `next(iter(fentry.keys()))` is the right way to do it. Thx

Answer (score 1):

You can join the two lists into a single list. Then sort the list by the dictionary keys. That will give you the keys next to each other. Check the adjacent element and if the keys match, then you can update your dictionary accordingly. If adjacent keys don't match, then set Values = False.

Here's the code to do it.

```
first_list = [{'W':['xyz','abc','def']},
              {'X':['1','2','3']},
              {'Y':['4','5','6']},
              {'Z':['1','5','7']}]

second_list = [{'X':True},{'Z':True}]

#combine the two lists, then sort the list by dictionary keys

combined = sorted(first_list + second_list, key=lambda d: sorted(d.keys()))

#setup a dictionary to store final result    
fs_final_dict = {}

#set index to 0
i = 0

#iterate through the dictionary and check for adjacent element

while i <= (len(combined)-1):
    if i == len(combined)-1:
        k1,v1 = [*combined[i].items()][0]
        fs_final_dict[k1] = {'deps':v1,'values':False}
        i+=1
    elif combined[i].keys() == combined[i+1].keys():
        k1,v1 = [*combined[i].items()][0]
        k2,v2 = [*combined[i+1].items()][0]
        fs_final_dict[k1] = {'deps':v1,'values':v2}
        i+=2
    else:
        k1,v1 = [*combined[i].items()][0]
        fs_final_dict[k1] = {'deps':v1,'values':False}
        i+=1
        
print (fs_final_dict)
```

The output will be:

```
{'W': {'deps': ['xyz', 'abc', 'def'], 'values': False}, 'X': {'deps': ['1', '2', '3'], 'values': True}, 'Y': {'deps': ['4', '5', '6'], 'values': False}, 'Z': {'deps': ['1', '5', '7'], 'values': True}}
```

A few test cases:

**Test Case 1: Passed**

```
second_list = [{'X':True},{'X':True}]
```

Output is:

```
{'W': {'deps': ['xyz', 'abc', 'def'], 'values': False}, 'X': {'deps': True, 'values': False}, 'Y': {'deps': ['4', '5', '6'], 'values': False}, 'Z': {'deps': ['1', '5', '7'], 'values': False}}
```

**Test Case 2: Passed**

```
second_list = [{'X':True},{'Y':True}]

{'W': {'deps': ['xyz', 'abc', 'def'], 'values': False}, 'X': {'deps': ['1', '2', '3'], 'values': True}, 'Y': {'deps': ['4', '5', '6'], 'values': True}, 'Z': {'deps': ['1', '5', '7'], 'values': False}}
```

**Test Case 3: Passed**

```
second_list = [{'X':True},{'W':True}]

{'W': {'deps': ['xyz', 'abc', 'def'], 'values': True}, 'X': {'deps': ['1', '2', '3'], 'values': True}, 'Y': {'deps': ['4', '5', '6'], 'values': False}, 'Z': {'deps': ['1', '5', '7'], 'values': False}}
```

**Test Case 4: Passed**

```
second_list = [{'W':True},{'Z':True}]

{'W': {'deps': ['xyz', 'abc', 'def'], 'values': True}, 'X': {'deps': ['1', '2', '3'], 'values': False}, 'Y': {'deps': ['4', '5', '6'], 'values': False}, 'Z': {'deps': ['1', '5', '7'], 'values': True}}
```

**Test Case 5: Passed**
Even though value of W is False, I am considering a value exists and I am populating the value in the second_list rather than overriding it with `True`. If we should make it `True`, then the code has to change.

```
second_list = [{'W':False},{'Z':True}]

{'W': {'deps': ['xyz', 'abc', 'def'], 'values': False}, 'X': {'deps': ['1', '2', '3'], 'values': False}, 'Y': {'deps': ['4', '5', '6'], 'values': False}, 'Z': {'deps': ['1', '5', '7'], 'values': True}}
```

**Test Case 6: Failed**
second_list has a key that is NOT in first_list. What do you want the code to do? Ignore key and value in second_list or store that as a new entry in final_list? The current code stores it as a new key.

```
second_list = [{'P':True},{'Z':True}]

{'P': {'deps': True, 'values': False}, 'W': {'deps': ['xyz', 'abc', 'def'], 'values': False}, 'X': {'deps': ['1', '2', '3'], 'values': False}, 'Y': {'deps': ['4', '5', '6'], 'values': False}, 'Z': {'deps': ['1', '5', '7'], 'values': True}}
```

**Test Case 7: Passed**
second_list has a key with the value in a list. I am considering it as a value that needs to be appended to final_list. Is this correct?

```
second_list = [{'W':[True]},{'Z':True}]

{'W': {'deps': ['xyz', 'abc', 'def'], 'values': [True]}, 'X': {'deps': ['1', '2', '3'], 'values': False}, 'Y': {'deps': ['4', '5', '6'], 'values': False}, 'Z': {'deps': ['1', '5', '7'], 'values': True}}
```

Answer (score 1):

**CODE**

```
first_list = [{'W':['xyz','abc','def']},{'X':['1','2','3']},{'Y':['4','5','6']},{'Z':['1','5','7']}]

second_list = [{'X':True},{'Z':True}]

first_dict = {key: value for elem in first_list for key, value in elem.items()}

second_dict = {key: value for elem in second_list for key, value in elem.items()}

newdict={key: {"dept": first_dict[key], "value": second_dict[key]} if key in list(second_dict.keys()) else {"dept": first_dict[key], "value": False} for key in list(first_dict.keys()) }

print(newdict)
```

output:

```
{'W': {'dept': ['xyz', 'abc', 'def'], 'value': False}, 'X': {'dept': ['1', '2', '3'], 'value': True}, 'Y': {'dept': ['4', '5', '6'], 'value': False}, 'Z': {'dept': ['1', '5', '7'], 'value': True}}
```

**EXPLAINATION**

first step:

```
first_dict = {key: value for elem in first_list for key, value in elem.items()}
```

here with a dict comprehension i merge all the dicts stored in `first_list`

output:

```
{'W': ['xyz', 'abc', 'def'],
 'X': ['1', '2', '3'],
 'Y': ['4', '5', '6'],
 'Z': ['1', '5', '7']}
```

second step:

```
second_dict = {key: value for elem in second_list for key, value in elem.items()}
```

here with a dict comprehension i merge all the dicts stored in `second_list`

output:

```
{'X': True, 'Z': True}
```

last step:

```
newdict={key: {"dept": first_dict[key], "value": second_dict[key]} for key in list(first_dict.keys()) if key in list(second_dict.keys())}
```

here with the last dict comprehension i generate the needed output

1. Iterating above `first_dict` i check if the keys are also in second_dict
2. if the condition occurres i create a new item in the dict, with the shared key as a key and a dict as a value, the nested dict contains under `"dept"` key the value from the `first_dict` and under the key `"value"` the value fron the `second_dict`
3. if the condition doesn't occurres i create a new item in the dict, with the non shared key as a key and a dict as a value, the nested dict contains under `"dept"` key the value from the `first_dict` and under the key `"value"` the value `False`